# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - Losing container full width on affix scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

- Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.7

I have the following two navs:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="topNavBar">
  <div class="container-fluid"></div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-lower" role="navigation" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="50" data-offset-bottom="80">
    <div class="container container-navbar">
        <div class="row take-test-heading">
            <asp:Label ID="lblTakeTestTitle" runat="server" Text="Take Text Title Here...."></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTakeTestTimeRemaining" runat="server" Text="00:00"></asp:Label>
            <i class="fa fa-bars pull-right"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="row take-test-heading-two">

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

with the following CSS:

```
body {
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}

.container-navbar {

}

.take-test-heading {
    background-color: rgb(51, 122, 183);
    height: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.navbar-lower {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

which gives me the following when the page is first rendered:

[image]

and then as I scroll (note the top affix):

[image]

I have a couple of issues that no matter what CSS changes I make I cannot seem to solve:

1. I want the blue bar "Take Text Title..." to be 100% and occupy the entire width of the viewport (yellow areas)
2. When scroll spy kicks in the navbar goes to 1170px (!) and is no longer full width (see green area). I want it to be full width all the time.

Cam someone please point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Would you mind adding a code snippet to reproduce the issue to your question.

Comment: As the doc says "Use the affix plugin via data attributes or manually with your own JavaScript. In both situations, you must provide CSS for the positioning and width of your affixed content." so you sould use something like: `left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: @ZohirSalak I cannot post a stand alone sample unfortunately. I am having to extend an existing site that is in production and pulling out all the other stuff is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 3 `.container` has 15px of `padding-left` and `padding-right`. You can set both to `0px;` manually.

Also setting `margin-left and margin-right` to 0px will do the trick

```
.take-test-heading {
    background-color: rgb(51, 122, 183);
    height: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```